# SDWebImage does not show an image although the image exist remotely on the server

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, uicollectionview, sdwebimage

I'm developing an iOS application and I'm using SDWebImage as an image downloader API.

I'm using a UICollectionView and I do it in the method

`- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(SMToplinksCollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

Some images are downloaded, and some are not. The ones that does not downloaded shows the error message:

> 2014-06-15 12:11:50.203 c_shadow_ios_iphone[6867:60b] ===Error:Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1100 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1100.)"

Error -1100: NSURLErrorFileDoesNotExist

Also, the UIImage seems to be nil.

I've checked the URL that SDWebImage tries to download and it gets me the image properly, so the Error does not seems reasonable

Here is the method code I use:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(SMToplinksCollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    
SMToplinkCollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:TopLinksCollectionViewID forIndexPath:indexPath];

NSArray *collectionViewArray = [self getToplinksArrayAccordingToTheIndex:collectionView.index];

//  CONFIGURE THE CELL
SMTopLinksObject *dataObject = collectionViewArray[indexPath.item];

//  1. Set the toplink title
cell.title     = dataObject.name;

//  2. Get the default image and blur it
cell.imageName = dataObject.localImageName;

//  3. Activate the preloader that shows the loading status

//  4. Load the image from the server
SDWebImageManager *manager = [SDWebImageManager sharedManager];
NSString *toplinksGetRequest = dataObject.prepareToplinksGetRequest;
NSURL *toplinksURL = [NSURL URLWithString:toplinksGetRequest];

NSLog(@"=== Trying to download image from URL:%@", toplinksGetRequest);
[manager downloadWithURL:toplinksURL
                 options:0
                progress:^(NSInteger receivedSize, NSInteger expectedSize){
                    //progression tracking code                        
                } completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, BOOL finished){
                    if(finished)
                    {
                        NSLog(@"===image finished loading, image:%@", image);
                        NSLog(@"===Error:%@", error);
                    }
                    if (image)
                    { cell.shadowPageImageView.image = image; }
}];    
NSLog(@"=========Cell:%@", cell);
return cell;
}
```

**Output**

> image is NIL
>
> Error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1100 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1100.)"

What do I miss here?

Comment: have you used UIImageView+AFNetworking for images?

Comment: I've used UIImageView+WebCache.h as it was suggested in the SDWebImage ReadMe

Comment: Do you resolve this? I have the similar issue. ty

Comment: Are you using storyboards?

Comment: I have the same issue , error saying that "trying to load nil url".

Answer (score 4):

```
[cell.diviceIV sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imgStringUrl] placeholderImage:nil options:SDWebImageRetryFailed completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL) {
    if (image){
        // Set your image over here
       }else{
           //something went wrong
       }

}];
```

The main point is options:SDWebImageRetryFailed option you need to give in your method.
It works for me you can try it out.

Comment: This "feature" (failedURLs) is basically a bug built right into SDWebImage. I would recommend to take a look at alternative frameworks (there are many).

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue.
I got "Error Domain=SDWebImageErrorDomain Code=-1 "Trying to load a nil url", but the image is present in that particular url.
I found that,the error occurs for low resolution images.
For better quality images , the loading happens well.
Check the same code for better resolution images.

Answer (score 2):

**First** make sure the image urls are https, not http. if so you would see following error on the log

> "The resource could not be loaded because the App Transport Security
>   policy requires the use of a secure connection."

If so add the following to your plist file

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Code is simple and straight forward

```
import SDWebImage

if let url = URL(string: "imageUrl") {
   yourImageView.sd_setImage(with: url, completed: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Download Latest Version SDWebImage from https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage and try again.

It will work.

Answer (score 0):

Try with following code

Import the category of imageView `#import <SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h>`
which is already in `SDWebImage`

Then in your cell for `cellForItemAtIndexPath`

```
[cell.imgVwUser sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:objPhoto.imageUrl] completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL) {
    DLogs(@"completed");

    [cell.loadIndicator stopAnimating];

}];
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem. I tried all the way mentioned above but could not work well.

Finally I found out the reason is the name of the url of image. I think that IOS does not support the Chinese name of image url. So you should be trans-coding the url.

**Example:**

```
url = [_img_url stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Answer (score 0):

> For me the issue was very low resolution images. For high resolution
>   images this works perfectly!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Use like this

```
self.imgUserProfile.sd_setImage(with: imageUrl, placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "profile_placeholder"), options: SDWebImageOptions.refreshCached, progress: nil, completed: { (image, error, cache, url) in
        if error == nil {
           self.imgUserProfile.image = image
       } 
  })
```